# Read File in android 4.4

Tags: android

I have file **xml** I put this file "**mnt/sdcard"** but I confuse how I can read file in **android 4.4** and where I put file xml in android **sdcard**, I need to put this file in spacial path or put this file any where for read in my app.
Can I replace this path"**mnt/sdcard/Pro.xml**" to dynamic path because this path change between version sdk in android.

```
Serializer serializer = new Persister();
File source = new File("mnt/sdcard/Pro.xml");
Pro  pro = serializer.read(Pr.class,source);
```

Comment: "mnt/sdcard" is not a valid path. Start with using "/mnt/sdcard/" instead. And yes there are functions who deliver such paths.